# How to animate UI button every 10 seconds?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I know this has never been asked and I guess this action would be very useful for any developer,

So I have a hint button and I really want to make it shake every 10 seconds to remind the user its there when they need it!

I know this might sound like a joke, but this is my code!

```
- (IBAction)ajutorBtn:(id)sender {
}
```

Actually I have some .hidden:YES; bools but I really need this function for the user base?

If possible I do accept tutorials as well...

Best!

Comment: What part do you need help with? Making the button shake? Doing it every 10 seconds? What have you tried? What research have you done?

Comment: Hey My question change!

Comment: I need the button to Shake every 10 seconds!

Comment: Yes. It has nothing to do with Xcode or the iPhone.

Comment: I know what you want to do. I'm asking you what part you need help with?

Comment: What does it have to do with?

Comment: I need help with the animation of the code that the button would shake! I can't find it on the web any where, I found a post on a wiggle, "Wiggle" but I need a some what shake or vibrating movement that occurs every 10 seconds!

Answer (score 1):

Use a repeating NSTimer. When the timer fires, do a "jiggle" animation of the button.